# javascript code won't run after while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am trying to write a loop that inspects a string to see if a stored variable is contained within the string, and then replaces that variable with the stored value. I have that part working fine, however after my while loop the code stops and will not run. Here is the code:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};

var sortedVarArray = [
  //[varName, value, units, complex?]
    ["d",         2,  null,        0],
    ["h",         3,  null,        0],
    ["u",   "d + h",  null,        1]
];

var value = 'u + 1';
var complex = true;

while (complex) {
    complex = false;
    for (var i = 0; i -1 < sortedVarArray.length; i++) {
        if (value.indexOf(sortedVarArray[i][0]) > -1 && sortedVarArray[i][3] == 1)
            complex = true;
        value = value.replaceAll(sortedVarArray[i][0], sortedVarArray[i][1]);
        if (complex) break;
    }
    output.innerHTML += "<br> hello";
}
output.innerHTML += "<br> hello2";

var result = eval(value);
output.innerHTML += "<br> result = " + result;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

so if, for example, I have an array `sortedVarArray` that looks like:

```
sortedVarArray = [
    ["varName", "value", "units", "complex?"]
    ["d", 2, null, 0]
    ["h", 3, null, 0]
    ["u", "d + h", null, 1]
]
```

and an equation `value` equal to `u + 1`

which, as the loop progresses, should change to look like this:

```
u + 1
d + h + 1
2 + h + 1
2 + 3 + 1
```

which will then evaluate to `6` at the end

My problem is that the code does not make it out of the `for` loop unless it `breaks`, and then it does not make it out of the `while` loop. and my code never evaluates.

I have a bunch of output messages in my code (cleaned up for here) and I can see that the string `value` is being modified as desired as the code loops. I am just not sure why it is not continuing after the loop ends.

Oh and if I change the code so that `complex` is declared as false, the loop is skipped and `"hello2"` is printed to `output`.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

EDIT: the ReplaceAll function is contained in the start of the script (outside of any function) and is as follows:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

Comment: `I have an array sortedVarArray that looks like` - not really, because that wouldn't be a valid array - are the d, h and u actually the strings "d", "h" and "u", or the values of d, h and u (which you don't share with us) ... is d + h actually the string "d + h" or the value d + h? also, what is `replaceAll` ? another function you haven't shared?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes they are strings. I have edited the original post to show that, and have added the replaceAll function.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? *"My problem is that the code does not make it out of the for loop unless it breaks"* - Why not? Nothing inside the `for` loop seems to modify the loop counter `i` or the array `sortedVarArray`, so why wouldn't the `for` loop end naturally when it gets to the end of the array?

Comment: Sorry they are headings I added to clarify what each value in the array represented. string quotes added to original post.

Comment: @DanW, I have edited your question to consolidate all of the information into one snippet which can be run on the page.  You can add/edit snippets by clicking on the icon above the edit field that is just to the right of the one that looks like a picture. Consolidating all the information into one block (when it all goes together; sometimes it is in multiple files; don't consolidate those). Having it in a snippet allows it to be easily checked (i.e. run) and permits people answering to copy the code into their answers with a single click (much more convenient). Feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: Thanks @Mayken. That's awesome what you've done. I'll keep that in mind next time i post a question. As i don't code very often it takes me ages to write and edit :)

Answer (score 2):

in your for loop:

```
i - 1 < sortedVarArray.length
```

will iterate your array for index 0 to length, where array[length] = undefined. try:

```
i < sortedVarArray.length
```

Comment: pfftt solved it! Thanks for that. I am a little embarrassed - for some reason I thought that `array.length` started counting at 0, as that's what VBA does. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @DanW - Array indices in JS *do* start at 0. That's why the last element in the array is at index `array.length - 1`. (But VB is weird because when you declare a VB array you specify the index of the last element, not the length.)

Comment: @nnnnn yes, but when you evaluate `array.length` it returns the number of elements, not the number of elements -1.  So if an array has 2 elements `array.length` would return `2` and the elements would be `array[0]` and `array [1]`

Comment: @DanW - Isn't that what I just said? (Though actually, in JS the array `.length` property *doesn't* tell you how many elements are in the array, it just tells you the index of the highest element plus one - which will be the number of elements in a dense array, but not in a sparse one: if you say `var arr = []; arr[100] = true;` then `arr.length` will be `101` but the array only has one element in it.)

Comment: @nnnnn it seems we are both on the same page :)